# Is there a method that can declare a variable automatically when it find a char in a file

Tags: c

For example

the text file contains a line : 
A B C
So the method will declare 3 variables: 
in A, B ,C;

Comment: No, at least not easily. You _could_ generate code with the variable declarations, compile it, and run the resulting program, or even (on some systems) dynamically load the newly compiled code into your original running program. A more reasonable way would be to build a data structure that maps fron strings to values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to create those dynamically.
One relatively easy option is to use [sys/queue.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/queue.3.html) if you have that header available. You use a struct with a link, key and value. When you need the value of A you travers the list and find the one with key A, and use its value.

Answer (score 1):

No . This type of facility is available in scripting languages like python and ruby but not in c/c++. You can use hashing or a struct to store this type of information.